# GraalVM: Preview features are not enabled for AsyncConfiguration (class file version 63.65535). Try running with '--enable-preview'

Tags: java, graalvm

Using the GraalVM Maven plug-in, I was prompted to turn on the preview feature when generating a local image (Spring Boot 3 application).

environment:

Windows 10

java -version:

openjdk version "19.0.1" 2022-10-18

OpenJDK Runtime Environment GraalVM CE 22.3.0 (build 19.0.1+10-jvmci-22.3-b08)

OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM GraalVM CE 22.3.0 (build 19.0.1+10-jvmci-22.3-b08, mixed mode, sharing)

command: mvn -Pnative spring-boot:run

Exception message:

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Preview features are not enabled for com/test/config/AsyncConfiguration (class file version 63.65535). Try running with '--enable-preview'
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1013)
        at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:150)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:862)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:681)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:639)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:495)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:474)
        at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:283)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinition.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:461)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doResolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1569)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1502)
        ... 16 common frames omitted
```

pom.xml

```xml
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

<build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.json</include>
                    <include>**/*.xml</include>
                    <include>**/*.yml</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <jvmArguments>
                        -agentlib:native-image-agent=config-merge-dir=src/main/resources/META-INF/native-image/
                    </jvmArguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>19</release>
                    <compilerArgs>
                        <arg>--enable-preview</arg>
                    </compilerArgs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.graalvm.buildtools</groupId>
                <artifactId>native-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <buildArgs>
                        <buildArg>--enable-preview</buildArg>
                    </buildArgs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

What should I do about it? thank you

Answer (score 0):

Just what the error message says -- add `--enable-preview` to your native-image invocation. The `AsyncConfiguration` class apparently uses some preview features of JDK19 such as record patterns or virtual threads (and if it doesn't, try recompiling it *without* the `--enable-preview` flag). In this case, both `java` and `native-image` require the flag to "unlock" preview features.

Comment: Thank you. I use mvn -Pnative spring-boot:run. How do I add --enable-preview?

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```xml
<build>
    <resources/>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <jvmArguments>-agentlib:native-image-agent=config-merge-dir=src/main/resources/META-INF/native-image/ --enable-preview
                    </jvmArguments>
                <compilerArguments>--enable-preview
                    </compilerArguments>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>19</source>
                <target>19</target>
                <compilerArgs>
                    <arg>--enable-preview</arg>
                </compilerArgs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.graalvm.buildtools</groupId>
            <artifactId>native-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <buildArgs combine.children="append">
                    <buildArg>--enable-preview</buildArg>
                </buildArgs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```